# Deployment failed in WildFly 8.2.0 Final

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I tried to deployed a war file in Wildfly 8.2.0 Server and while I'm enabling the war it is throwing the following errors.

```
Failed to enable nxp-bd-server.war.
Unexpected HTTP response: 500
Request{
"address" => [("deployment" => "nxp-bd-server.war")],
"operation" => "deploy"}Response
Internal Server Error{
"outcome" => "failed",
"failure-description" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./nxp-bd-server.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.sp]"]},
"rolled-back" => true}
```

Is there any other configuration am I missing?

Deployed the sqljdbc-4.0.jar first

Comment: Ok, the error says something about a security domain which is missing. But without information about the war and your setup we are hardly able to give you a hint.

Comment: There was an issue with data source configuration and I fixed that..While enabling the war again showing the following error.

`Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/Hibernate4SspDS is already registered`

Comment: Is your problem now fixed or is that the next exception you are facing? If so please provide configuration snippets.

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31963449/4917517. Try to cleanup the deployments section. Might be the same problem.

```
<deployments>
    //remove this part
    <deployment name="your_file.war" runtime-name="your_file.war">
        <fs-archive path=".../your_file.war"/>
    </deployment>
    ...
</deployments>
```