# Wildfly 10: Cannot upload deployment, Required services that are not installed

Tags: postgresql, deployment, wildfly

Every time I deploy a war file in wildfly 10, I got this following error :

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"member.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"member.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153:
>   Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"member.war\"
>   Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYJCA0064: Exception deploying datasource java:/PostgresDS Caused
>   by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service
>   jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.PostgresDS\" is already
>   registered"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:"
>   => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"member.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE"],"WFLYCTL0180:
>   Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}

It happens when I changed my **persistence.xml** and ***-ds.xml** which is telling my application to use the *PostgresDS* as its **datasource**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the files, it seems like you are registering your data source twice, once in the *-ds.xml and once in the persistence.xml (or maybe in the standalone.xml?).

Regarding missing/unavailable dependencies, are you certain the the Postgres SQL Module is installed in Wildfly and the driver is configured in the standalone.xml?

See also:

- [Wildfly DuplicateServiceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509729/wildfly-duplicateserviceexception)
- [How to add PostgreSQL datasource to WildFly 9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222860/how-to-add-postgresql-datasource-to-wildfly-9-0)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've removed the -ds.xml, but I'm still having an error about Services with missing/unavailable dependencies.